# Continuous Scrolling Through Desktops on Lion

Tags: macos, mission-control

I have a few desktops set up in mac and and browser with my calendar and mail in full screen mode.  In total I normally have 3 running.  I also have custom hotkey to quickly scroll through the desktops, but when I get to the last one how do can I make it cycle through to the beginning.

For example if I'm on the 3rd of three desktops, is there a way I can go the right to a 4th, but since it's not there it will go back to the 1st.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe there currently is any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TheWellington is right, sadly. Using the Keyboard pane in System Prefs, you can still assign Command-n to take you to the nth desktop, though. So Command-1 (or whatever your favorite hotkey is) would take you to the first space from the third.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, this feature was removed along with some others when apple moved from Expose/Spaces to Mission Control.